# Neo4J Cypher: Set property only if it is null but still return the node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am quite new to Neo4J and struggling with the following:

I want to set property only if it does not exist yet (if it's null) and do not want to set property if it exists.
How can I modify the query below to achieve that

```
  MATCH (u:User)
  WHERE u.uuid=$userId
  SET u.unsubscribedAt = timestamp()
  RETURN u
```

Thanks in advance

UPDATE 1:
One thing I forgot to mention: I still want to return the node regardless, so cannot add `AND u.unsubscribedAt is null` in where clause

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [coalesce](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-coalesce) to achieve this. It returns the first non-null value it's passed, so it will resolve the existing value if already present

```
  MATCH (u:User)
  WHERE u.uuid=$userId
  SET u.unsubscribedAt = coalesce(u.unsubscribedAt, timestamp())
  RETURN u
```

Answer (score 3):

What about adding the property as a discriminator for the match?

```
  MATCH (u:User)
  WHERE u.uuid=$userId AND IS NULL u.unsubscribedAt
  SET u.unsubscribedAt = timestamp()
  RETURN u
```

Comment: I still want to return the node, updated the question

Answer (score 1):

if you do not mind the property being overwritten with its original value, you could also do this :

```
MATCH (u:User {uuid:$userId})
SET u.unsubscribedAt = COALESCE(u.unsubscribedAt,timestamp())
RETURN u
```

Comment: thanks, just accepted Thomas's answer, which is identical, but upvoted yours, thanks for the help

Comment: No problem. Mine is shorter ;) Happy graphing !